# Медленный цикл с векторами в С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, vector

Здравствуйте , есть такой код :

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
std::vector<std::string> code_book_characters;
std::vector<size_t> codeword_length;
std::vector<double> words_dictionary;
std::vector<double> result;
... // заполнениe векторов , reserve для result
    for (int i = 0; i < 345600; ++i)
    {
        int ncode = -1;
        bool flag = false;
        while (( !flag ) && ( ncode+1 < n_code ))
        {
            ++ncode;
            std::vector<unsigned char> val_1 { &buffer[m_buffer],&buffer[m_buffer + codeword_length[ncode]] };
            std::vector<unsigned char> tmp_compare (code_book_characters[ncode].begin(), code_book_characters[ncode].end()); 
            flag = std::equal(val_1.begin(), val_1.end(), tmp_compare.begin());
        }
        m_buffer += codeword_length[ncode];
        result.emplace_back(words_dictionary[ncode]);
    } return result;
```

Что делает:

1. Создали вектор val_1 из большого buffer(используя m_buffer как
   начало нового вектора и размер codeword из codeword_length)
2. Создали и заполнили второй вектор tmp_compare ( из словаря code_book_characters)
3. Проверили сходится ли val_1 и tmp_compare
   Да - 3.1.переходим к следующему слову из buffer
   Нет - Шаг 2 с новым словом из словаря

Все это повторяеться пока в bufferе есть данные.

Можно ли его переписать/изменить более оптимально с точки зрения скорости , потому что на производство каждого `result` уходит ~10 секунд.

**EDIT:**
Изменение

```
std::vector<unsigned char> tmp_compare;
                for (auto c : code_book_characters[ncode])
                {
                    tmp_compare.emplace_back(c);
                }
```

на

```
std::vector<unsigned char> tmp_compare (code_book_characters[ncode].begin(), code_book_characters[ncode].end());
```

Уменьшило время с 10 до 3 секунд .

Comment: Опишите саму поставленную задачу - из кода без единого комментария  не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Очень может быть, что нужно просто кардинально менять алгоритм...

Comment: Я тоже боюсь что нужно менять алгоритм но была надежда на более мягкое решение чем кардинальные изменения.
Обновил - нужно больше деталей или уже лучше ?

Comment: Т.е. задача сводится к тому, чтобы в одной строке (пусть и большой) найти слова, помещенные в массиве строк? И ради этого Вы создаете на каждой итерации вложенного цикла динамические массивы (по 2 штуки)? Еще бы оно не тормозило... А простой std::find() не справляется с поиском (при уловии, что создание массивов Вы сможете вынести за циклы)?

Comment: В принципе да -> взять слово из потока -> найти его в другом потоке (словаре) -> записать значение.  Стыдно , я действительно забыл про std::find . Должно прекрасно отработать. Пожалуйста , продублируйте ваш комментарий ответом чтобы я мог засчитать его как ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: У вас на каждую вставку в result возможна доаллокация - сделайте reserve вашему вектору перед вставкой в него толпы элементов.

Comment: Уточнил в вопросе - reserve был сделан .

Comment: На самом деле, если входной поток - это большой файл и дело происходит под Windows, то можно для него использовать отображение в память (под unix отображение файлов на память тоже есть, но про скорость работы с ним у меня нет опыта - не могу ничего сказать) и не копировать лишний раз во временные строки. Это тоже может сократить итоговое время поиска, т.к. повторное обращение к таким файлам происходит очень быстро (ну, и минус операция копирования во вложенных циклах).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То есть задача сводится к тому, чтобы в одной строке (пусть и большой) найти слова, помещенные в массиве строк? И ради этого Вы создаете на каждой итерации вложенного цикла динамические массивы (по 2 штуки)? Возможно, стандартный std::find() справится с задачей быстрее, особенно, если Вы объявление `val_1` и `tmp_compare` вынесете за пределы циклов (с заданием достаточного начального размера через `reserve`).

Answer (score 1):

Для эффективного поиска множества строк в одном тексте есть специальные алгоритмы - например, алгоритм [Ахо-Корасик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA).
Для С++ нетрудно найти реализацию

Вот и другие из англ. вики:

> Algorithms using a finite set of patterns
>   Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm (extension of Knuth-Morris-Pratt)
>   Commentz-Walter algorithm  (extension of Boyer-Moore)
>   Set-BOM (extension of Backward Oracle Matching)
>   Rabin–Karp string search algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб найти в последовательности другую:

```
string s1 = "stack overflow... we can always find a good method";
char p[] = "way";    
auto It = std::search(s1.begin(), s1.end(), p, &p[strlen(p)]);
if (It != s1.end()) cout << "word found \"" << p <<'\"';
```